# Lifecyle of an actor in actor model

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm a newbie to actor model.  Could anyone please explain the lifecycle of an actor in actor model?  I've been looking for the answer in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything satisfactory.

I'm interested in what an actor does after it completes the `onReceive()` method - is it still alive or is it dead?  Can we control its lifetime to say "don't die, wait there for the next message"?  For example, with a round-robin router, if I set it to have 5 actors - would it always distribute the work across the **same** 5 actors?  Or actors are destroyed and created anytime there is a message, but the maximum limit is always 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Actor` is always alive unless you explicitly "kill" it (or it crashes somehow). When it receives a message, it will "use" a thread, process the message, then go back to an "idle" state. When it receives another message, it becomes "active" again.

In the case of a round-robin router with 5 `Actor`s, it is the same 5 `Actor`s - the router does not create new ones each time a message is sent to the router.

The Actor model follows an "isolated mutability" (concurrency) model - it encapsulates state only to itself - other `Actor`s are not able to touch this state directly, they can only interact with it via message passing. The `Actor`s must be "alive" in order to keep the state.